# NuxtJS Socket.io not working in production

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to use socket.io in a NuxtJS SSR app. But unfortunatly it only works on dev. As soon as I build and start in production it doesn't work anymore. I tried multiple ways of doing it (explained at the end), and I had always the same output. This version, using nuxt hooks, is the cleanest which works nice on dev.

This is my server-side module (modules/ws.js) :

```js
import socketIO from 'socket.io'

export default function () {
  this.nuxt.hook('listen', (server, { host, port }) => {
    console.log(`ListentHook : Listening on http://${host}:${port}`)
    const io = socketIO(server)

    io.on('connection', (ws) => {
      console.log('Client connected')
      ws.on('message', (message) => {
        console.log('received: %s', message)
      })
      ws.emit('message', 'Hello new client')
    })
  })
}
```

Client side, I have a plugin (plugins/socket.io.js) :

```js
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const socket = io('http://localhost:3000')

export default socket
```

And on my vue, i import that client socket ang listen for messages (pages/index.vue) :

```js
<script>
import socket from '~/plugins/socket.io.js'

export default {
  name: 'Index',
  beforeMount () {
    socket.on('message', this.printMsg)
  },
  methods: {
    printMsg (msg) {
      console.log(msg)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And this is my nuxt.config.js file :

```js
...
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    '~/modules/ws'
  ],
...
```

In development mode it work nicely.
When I load http://localhost:3000 i get :

> "Client connected" on server side

> "Hello new client" on client side

Now, when I build the application nothing works, and I only get an error in the client console :

> GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NSauEZA
> 404 (Not Found)

I realy do not understand why.

**What I already did :**

Tested the official nuxt with-sockets example :
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/with-sockets
--> Same results (Nuxt standalone version)

Look up, and posted on that gitHub issue :
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6928
--> Same results

Tested to put .env variables
--> Same results (and with working env vars changing the actual server port)

Thanks for your help !!
And I can provide more code if needed !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your module is a server middleware that runs WS, so you have to declare it in the `modules` array of your `nuxt.config.js` file instead of the `buildModules` array, to be run on production.

As explained in the [Nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-modules#buildmodules), the `buildModules` are only used during development and build time.

Comment: I tested so much things and the solution was so easy and obvious ... Thanks a lot !